# Continuous sub-form not going to "last record"

Tags: vba, ms-access

So I've created a form (Only accessible/loadable by those with a developer security level ID) that allows me to input an SQL statement into an unbound text box and execute.

If the statement fails it populates a continuous subform within the form with the fail error/description but after a quick me.refresh it jumps to the first record and no matter what I try I cannot get it to jump to the last record.

I've tried:

```
Me.sub_ConsoleRTN.Form.ConsoleRTN.MoveLast
```

and also:

```
Me.sub_ConsoleRTN.Form.ConsoleRTN.SetFocus
DoCmd.RunCommand accmdRecordsGoToLast
```

and they run with no errors but do not show the last record

Here is the full code:

```
Private Sub ExecuteSQL_Click()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim strSQL As String
Dim myCI As String

myCI = txt_sqlConsole.Value

If myCI = "" Then
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_ADM_Console " & "(ErrNumber,ErrDescription) VALUES" & "(101, 'Cannot exectute blank statement')"
    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
    Me.txt_actionconf.Value = "Action cancelled - compile error"
    Me.Refresh
    Me.sub_ConsoleRTN.Form.ConsoleRTN.SetFocus
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToLast
        Else
        strSQL = myCI
        CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
        Me.txt_actionconf.Value = "Action completed"
        Me.Refresh
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acLast

    End If

Exit_ExecuteSQL:                         ' Label to resume after error.
Exit Sub                                 ' Exit before error handler.

ErrorHandler:                            ' Label to jump to on error.
     Call logConsoleErrors(Err.Number, Err.Description, "Console()")
     Me.txt_actionconf.Value = "Action cancelled - compile error"
     Me.Refresh
     Resume Exit_ExecuteSQL

End Sub
```

As always I'm probably missing something very simple, but sources on the internet kind of suggest that "Me.sub_ConsoleRTN.Form.ConsoleRTN.SetFocus
DoCmd.RunCommand accmdRecordsGoToLast" is the correct method to try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call this code - here included in the *OnLoad* event:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim rs  As DAO.Recordset

    Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
    If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
        rs.MoveLast
        Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
    End If
    rs.Close

End Sub
```

And if your form is bound to *tbl_ADM_Console*, you can skip all the code and just use `AddNew` on the `RecordsetClone`.

Comment: This is great! - From initial tests it works when there is data in the table.

Related fault - the table clears when form is closed so opening on a blank table means it will error. I was thinking of putting an IF statement in but I actually ended up breaking it.

Comment: Yes. I've expanded the code to take care of no records. See edited answer, pleaser.